# using the JSTS library type bindings for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jts

I recently faced difficulties using the [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) library and its type bindings for Typescript and though in the end I made it work and I don't fully understand why.

I started off by installing JSTS and its bindings:

```
npm i --S jsts
npm i --D @types/jsts
```

Initially I tried the following in my code:

```
import jsts from 'jsts';
const {OL3Parser} = jsts.io;
const parser = new OL3Parser();
```

The above type-checked with no errors but crashed at runtime with: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'io' of undefined`.

Also, if I were to try to type the `parser` variable in the above example as follows:

```
const parser: OL3Parser = new OL3Parser();
```

… then I would get:

```
TS2749: 'OL3Parser' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof OL3Parser'?
```

I then tried:

```
import OL3Parser from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/OL3Parser';
```

This failed typechecking with:

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/OL3Parser'.
```

Following some online research I ended up with:

```
const jsts = require('jsts');
const parser: jsts.io.OL3Parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
```

The above both type-checks and works as intended but I don't like the long qualified names and I don't understand why it is that I have to use the library in this particular way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `jsts` as follows:

```js
import * as jsts from 'jsts';
```

The reason for this is, that `jsts` does rather export a namespace object instead of a named export or default export.

So using the above aproach imports the complete namespace of the module into a single variable, which than provides further access to various `jsts` classes.

For example:

```js
const reader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in my case. Only the `require` approach I mention in my original question works for me.

Comment: Do you build your source code through a tool like Typescript or Babel? Can you show your configuration?